How do I make an SQLite database readable only by my app?
I have a database file created by my .Net 7 Maui app on Android:
public static class Constants
{
    public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags OpenFlags =
        // open the database in read/write mode
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite |
        // create the database if it doesn't exist
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |
        // enable multi-threaded database access
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;

    public const SQLite.CreateFlags CreateFlags =
        SQLite.CreateFlags.None;

}

static public SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;
Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("some path", Constants.OpenFlags);

The database stores data used by my app. How do I make it readable only by my app?

Normally files in your apps data folder are only accessible by your app unless the phone is rooted

You can encrypt your database
   
using SQLite;

var options = new SQLiteConnectionString(_databasePath, true, "password", postKeyAction: c =>
            {
                c.Execute("PRAGMA cipher_compatibility = 3");
            });
            _database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(options);
            await _database.CreateTableAsync<Obj>();



There is no such pragma in the documentation: PRAGMA Statements

I use sqlite-net-sqlcipher https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/

sharp
using System.IO;

// Specify the path to your SQLite database file
string databaseFilePath = "path_to_your_database_file.db";

// Set the file's read-only attribute
File.SetAttributes(databaseFilePath, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);


If the file is readonly, how can the app write on it ? And what prevents other apps from reading it's content ? Out of topic answer.
